# Data Binding is not working with Ionic Cards

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Alright, I have an html page that contains an ionic card but when I bind data to its items they are not shown at the browser so what is the problem

```
<ion-view title="Game" ng-controller="GameCtrl as vm">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="item">
                Home Team
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              {{vm.game.team1}}
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                Score: {{vm.game.team1Score}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and here is the angular controller for this page :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('eliteApp').controller('GameCtrl', ['$stateParams','eliteApi', GameCtrl]);

    function GameCtrl($stateParams, eliteApi) {
        var vm = this;

        var gameId = Number($stateParams.id);
        var data = eliteApi.getLeagueData();
        vm.game = _.find(data.games,{"id": gameId});

    };
})();
```

I injected the js file to index.html; while tracing the debugging the function is getting data but data is not viewed at the browser so can anybody have some help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('eliteApp').controller('GameCtrl', ['$stateParams','eliteApi', function($stateParams, eliteApi){
 var gameId = Number($stateParams.id);
    var data = eliteApi.getLeagueData();
    this.game = _.find(data.games,{"id": gameId});
}]);
```

**Edit**

Looks like you're missing a route with a game id. Add this to your .config function:

```
 .state('app.game-detail', {
    url: "/game/:id",
    views: {
      "mainContent":{
        templateUrl: "app/game/game.html"
      }
    }
  })
```

And change your team-detail.html with this:

```
  <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="game in vm.games"
           href="#/app/game/{{game.gameId}}">
```

It should work now.

Comment: it didn't works the same result is coming up no data is shown.. :/

Comment: when tracing it gives that vm.game (game undefined) but why is that ?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: I didn't ever use it but I have it GitHub if u want to take look please, its a cordova app project m working on

Comment: Sure. can you post the link?

Comment: I grabbed it. I'll take a look at it now.

Comment: See my edits. I was able to get your app to work with those changes.